# How do I get one object instance’s keys in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I try to calculate add number values. For example,

> **Input:** `{i: 10, j: 20}`
>
> **Output:** `30`

So I try this code:

```
var Sample = function(x,y){
     this.a = x;
     this.b = y;
}
Sample.prototype.c = 30;
Sample.prototype.totalSum = function (){
                                  return this.a+this.b+this.c
                           };
var ins1 = new Sample(10,20);
console.log(Object.keys(ins1));
console.log(ins1.totalSum());
```

Its output:

```
["a", "b"]
60
```

But I expected two other possible answers. This (one):

```
["a", "b", "c"]
60
```

or this (two):

```
["a", "b"] // a = 10; b = 20; c = undefined;
NaN
```

Why did this code not output either of these answers?

Comment: Because "_The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties ..._" `c` is not an _own_  property of your object. See [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) at MDN.

Comment: You cannot add a property to the prototype but have to do this in the constructor, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp)

Comment: But see the totalSum method  am added this.a , this.b & this.c ok.It added successfully. This refer ins1 Object. So why can't get "c" key

Comment: Ok, you can add the property to the prototype, but I meant it won't be propagated to your existing object instance of Sample (ins1). This is only done during the initialization of the instance.

Comment: @ObethSamuel You can access `.c` just fine, it's only `Object.keys` that doesn't list it. Notice that it also doesn't list other inherited properties like `totalSum` or `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: `this.a` and `this.b` exist in both, the instance and the prototype, but `this.c` is only created in the prototype, that's why your function kind of "works"

Comment: @Steve this.a and this.b exist in instance only .They Not exist prototype